# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.propTypes') - React Native 0.61.5

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have upgraded the existing react native project from react native 0.59.6 to 0.61.5.

react-native upgrade command not working. So I have done the manual upgrade using upgrade helper. Resolved some post issues. Now project build success.

But After rendering into the ios emulator from Xcode, it is giving the following error.

[image: iPhone XR emulator screenshot]

I am not using Component.propTypes anywhere. package.lock.json have some packages with prop-types. I am not sure what it is doing exactly. Otherwise, inside my project, I am not using 
prop-types also. Please find my package.lock.json below,

**package.lock.json**

```js
...
...
...

 "prop-types": {
      "version": "15.7.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/prop-types/-/prop-types-15.7.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-8QQikdH7//R2vurIJSutZ1smHYTcLpRWEOlHnzcWHmBYrOGUysKwSsrC89BCiFj3CbrfJ/nXFdJepOVrY1GCHQ==",
      "requires": {
        "loose-envify": "^1.4.0",
        "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
        "react-is": "^16.8.1"
      }
    },
....
"react": {
      "version": "16.9.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-16.9.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-+7LQnFBwkiw+BobzOF6N//BdoNw0ouwmSJTEm9cglOOmsg/TMiFHZLe2sEoN5M7LgJTj9oHH0gxklfnQe66S1w==",
      "requires": {
        "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
        "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2"
      }
    },
....
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "wasfat",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "app/assets/fonts/corbel"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepare-repository": "npm i -g react-native-cli yarn;yarn install; react- native link",
    "emulator": "emulator -avd Nexus5V6L23_x86_64 -scale 1.0",
    "clean": "watchman watch-del-all && npm cache clean && cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "rm -rf node_modules/react-native-twitter-signin/node_modules",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-android-keyboard-adjust": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-deep-linking": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-double-tap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.8",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-hide-with-keyboard": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.25.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-avoiding-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-view": "0.0.14",
    "react-native-keyboard-listener": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.6",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-responsive-image": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-s3-upload": "0.0.12",
    "react-native-share": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-side-drawer": "^1.1.9",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-twitter-signin": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.4",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-video-player": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-spinkit": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I have found this https://reactjs.org/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html regarding this issue. But I am not sure how to use it. Because according to this. some third party libraries using propTypes directly. But how to handle it?

There is no help in 0.61 version Github issues. Please suggest some workarounds for this issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please share the code of the file where you have used propTypes ?

Comment: Hey Saadi, Thanks for the reply. But that is the problem. I am not using propTypes anywhere in my files. I think some third party libraries using the propTypes. But I am not able to find in node-modules also.

Comment: try updating react-native-gesture-handler to 1.5.2

Comment: Can you please tell me when do you see the error? Right after running or when you navigate to a specific screen ? Please share the code of that screen if possible

Comment: I updated react-native-gesture-handler to 1.5.2. But still the same error. I am getting this red screen right after running.

Comment: Also, I found an issue on the Github gesture-handler page. But there is no solution. https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/887#issue-541219894

Comment: try `grep -r propTypes ./node_modules`

Comment: Thanks kenmistry. Before trying this command, I have uninstalled and re installed the gesture-handler package. Linked using react-native link react-native-gesture-handler. I am not sure it is necessary or not. Even though it is not necessary to link manually, I have read somewhere in react native release notes, this auto-linking feature is not tested for all the libraries. So that some libraries we still might need to do the manual linking using react-native link command. After link command, it works